# Let A be a commutative ring and let B be a commutative A-algebra.

Tags: modules

Let A be a commutative ring and let B be a commutative A-algebra. Let d be a positive integer, and let M be an A-module satisfying $\operatorname{Tor}_A^n(B,M)=0 ~~$for $~0\lt n\le d~.$  Prove that for any B-module N there exists an isomorphism $\operatorname{Ext}_B^m(B\otimes_A M,N)\cong \operatorname{Ext}_A^m(M,N)$ for every $m\leq d$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).